# desabilitar um botão em php pelo com status em banco de dados

Tags: php

como faço para criar um botão em php que quando tiver algum status no banco de dados ele fique desabilitado, 
quando não tiver status no banco de dados ele fique Habilitado

Comment: Botão no PHP? Está implementando uma interface gráfica com PHP ou esse botão é HTML?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverFlow por favor consulte o seguinte link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Você pode criar um bool no banco de dados (true ou false) e quando for false, você vai verificar com ajax e desabilitar o mesmo, quando for true, você habilita. Faça com Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponho que você esteja usando o PHP misturado com o HTML, então ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

    // restante do código onde você pega o status no banco e guarda na variável $status_banco, por exemplo

    $status_botao = $status_banco == true ? "" : "disabled";

    // seta a propriedade 'disabled' do botão de acordo com o status
    print "<button ".$status_botao."> Botão </button>";
?>
```

Porém, o ideal mesmo é separar completamente o código PHP do HTML, pesquise um pouco sobre templates PHP.